# Google sheets not recognising a date as a date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[On this report](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DGAWyJ63A8QaDqyYp140S7UQz6_4iGFQSaK3118RVQU/edit?usp=sharing) I am trying to do some date analysis.

In column G I need to pull all the URLs from column A which have a closing date in the next 7 days.
And in column I, I need all the URLs which the closing date is in the past.

The issue is that when I try to reference the Closing dates in column E it does not read and as such work.

Could I get some help on making sheets read Column E properly and also some help on the formulas I need in Column G and I

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at the `DATEVALUE` function:

`=DATEVALUE(D2)`

If cell `D2` contains a date in the form of text (such as `"26 May 2022"`), this formula will return the date as a number. (You can then format the cell to display a particular date format if required.)

For URLs which have ended, you can then do:

`=F2 < TODAY()`

And for URLs ending in the next 7 days you will need something like:

```
=IF(F2<TODAY(), FALSE, IF(F2 - TODAY() > 7, FALSE, TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you this is incredibly helpful!, is there a way to make it retrieve the actual URL instead of displaying False?

Comment: Yes, you can just replace `FALSE` (or `TRUE`) with the cell reference of the cell containing the URL - `A2`, say.